# Access VBA "&" special character within a string

Tags: vba, ms-access, special-characters

I can't seem to output a string with the "&" sign in it.

I am trying to create a hyperlink where there is an "&" sign but Access seems to think its an & sign that merges two things rather then being part of the string.

```
Me.lblHyperlink.HyperlinkAddress = "Http://somelink.com/admin/info?id=" & Me.txtFolderID & Chr(38) & "tab-id=" & Me.txtAccountID
```

or

```
Me.lblHyperlink.HyperlinkAddress = "Http://somelink.com/admin/info?id=" & Me.txtFolderID & "&tab-id=" & Me.txtAccountID
```

These do not work...

Comment: Both look good to me, what output do you actually see?

Comment: It displays the whole thing but without that "&" in the string funny part is when I make a msgbox call with that same string it shows the "&"

Comment: Only the hyperlink field seems to have issues, a regular text box shows the "&"...Need to find if I can make the txtboc a hyperlink.

Comment: This is just a wild guess but try to put `~` in front of the `&`.

Comment: `&&` escapes `&` in normal labels (or disabling use accelerator) but I'm not familiar with access hyperlinks.

Comment: you need to URLEncode each parameter.

Comment: OK thanks I'll try to see if I can figure how to URLEncode.

Comment: The second snippet works for me. I'd also like to see the result you're getting. Are you sure there are values in txtFolderID and txtAccountID? make sure you check those.

Comment: Both syntax work for me so has to be issue with data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an extra & in front of the one you want to appear in the string. For example: " This && That" will end up as "This & That"